# Publish an external file in wwwroot

Tags: visual-studio-2015, asp.net-core

this is my project structure. In the root folder I have an `src` folder with a project into it.

```
/
- src
    - MyProject
        - wwwroot
            - xxx
        - Program.cs
        - Startup.cs
- MyFolder
    - Myfile.txt
```

At the same level of the `src` folder I have another folder with inside a file.
I would like to publish `Myfile.txt` inside the folder `xxx`, which is inside the `wwwroot` folder.

I have tried with the following publishOptions

```
"publishOptions": {
    "include": [
        "wwwroot",
        "web.config",
        "../../MyFolder/Myfile.txt"
    ]
},
```

but instead it creates the folder at the same level of `wwwroot` and not under it.

Is there any way that I can achieve this result?